# Trying to identify Mikuni carburators on a 2.0l ford zetec engine

Tags: carburetor, part-identification

The only information I can find on them is stamped on the side, G549.A, T5X6, I believe they came off a Yamaha motorcycle.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this some sort of conversion? Zetecs had fuel injection as standard imho...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Yes, this engine is in a 1963 Morris Minor 1000, I believe the conversion was done in the early 2000's, I'm trying to find rebuild kits for them, I believe these came off a Yamaha R1